# Google cardboard, barrel, lens distorsion for a static image

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cardboard

**Input**: the couple of the left and right stereoscopic image;
**Desired output**: the image formatted as Google cardboard expects, e.g.:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/vNacK7nx0HXU1g28FyqfnjYbaF0SKe86nDXhgetSfG8HTcsbhc7QcJtalcRHUEgU2A4k=h900-rw

I was wondering if I could get the barrel/lens distortion using Core Image Filter API for iOS.
If not, a "pixel" level algorithm would be also useful.
I don't want to use google cardboard sdk because I'm not using 3d scenes and openGL in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You will somehow need to get the lens distortion parameters, since different viewers will have different lens parameters.  The easiest way to do this is to use the Cardboard SDK.

However, if you know the lens distortion parameters ahead of time, you can use the [Brown-Conrady model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion_(optics)) to perform the correction yourself.